# How to upgrade alsamixer in ubuntu 13

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, sound, alsa

I resonantly ran a script which I thought would upgrade alsamixer, I think it downgraded it. Whatever it did I now get crackly sound. I now have alsamixer version 1.0.16. I have heard that there is a 1.0.27 version, how do I upgrade to this version of alsamixer?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: What script did you run?

Comment: The script from this webpage. http://www.stchman.com/alsa_update.html

Comment: `This script updated 9/6/2007`

Comment: You need to reinstall the `alsa-lib` and `alsa-utils` packages, reinstall the current kernel (or update to a newer kernel), and remove the `model=3stack` line from the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base`. (Somebody with knowledge of the Ubuntu package manager please write an answer.)

Comment: Ok thanks CL that fixed it, I think I am even getting better audio than before I did the downgrade. Probably because of kernel 3.9. I'll post an answer with the steps I took soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that this is for a 64bit system.

**Step one: Reinstall alsa-utils**

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils --reinstall
```

**Step two: Download and install alsa-lib**

[Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/alsa-lib_1.0.25.orig.tar.bz2) is a link to version 1.0.25-4(the stable version)

Extract the archive and run the following code in the extracted directory

```
./configure && make
```

Then

```
sudo make install
```

**Step three: Update Kernel**

I'm not sure if this is required but I did it anyway

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-raring/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-raring/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_all.deb   
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-raring/linux-image-3.9.0-030900-generic_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo update-grub
```

This will update your kernel to kernel 3.9 which does have some audio improvements.

Thanks to [CL.](https://askubuntu.com/users/90892/cl) for the info.

Aaron Rolls