# Pressing back space inputs characters

Tags: skype

So recently I just installed Ubuntu 13.04, and I have serious problems with Skype. So first of all and that worries me most is that after some time I can't write in chats.

For example, if I'm pressing "backspace" in Skype chat it behaves strange. With every click it starts to write different symbols - like, if I press backspace, it will write "p", second press will write "m" and etc and everytime its in some sort of pattern, like, pressing 12 times backspace it will do something like this "pmgh m pmgh m".

And it's exactly the same with every symbol on keyboard. After that, I can only do a Skype restart and everything then is normal for some time, then it will start all over (but every symbol will have a different patterns). If this would be Windows I would definitely think I have some sort of virus or some sort of script that changes symbols (because it's in patterns),

I have no idea whats happening here. But, the thing is, I have been running Ubuntu for a 3-4 days, and nothing is affected with this behavior, just Skype.

Could someone try to elaborate whats happening?

Second thing is after some time Skype starts to have a strange crackling sound - and again, to solve this I can only do restart. Maybe someone knows whats going on?

Comment: There doesn't exist any Viruses for Ubuntu.

Comment: Same problem for me on Ubuntu 13.10. I reinstall Skype but it seems unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove skype and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
```

Then do a sudo update. Make sure no packages are showing errors.

Then reinstall skype but also upgrade afterwards like this.

```
sudo apt-get install skype
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Since it is a sound problem try this thread:

[Alsa Mixer Update 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328784/how-to-upgrade-alsamixer-in-ubuntu-13)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that, but maybe you know what could the problem of this? It's just sounds completely illogical - if there is a problem, it should persist always (not after some time), and everytime it's different pattern. I'm just very interesting what could be the reason that skype behaves like this.

Comment: I see your point. I've had my internet connection cut out during updates or installations before and it messed up the application. Even if it cut out for one second, I had to do the process I showed you above.

Also, make sure you are using the latest network drivers.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry also install alsa-mixer. This could be the problem with the sound. Do the alsa-mixer first it will be easier. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks, but with the sound problem it didn't helped. I'm using ubuntu temporary so for now i just disabled all sounds in skype and it seems to be okay now. And with key-related problems re-install helped. Thanks again!