# Random character input starts after typing during short freezes

Tags: keyboard, skype, input

I've been experiencing a weird behavior with some applications (e. g. Skype), since I updated my Ubuntu to 13.10 and now to Ubuntu 14.04.

When my computer "freezes" due to high CPU usage and I happen to type something in the application at the same time, the application starts to input the characters I've typed during the freeze randomly. I can type some characters correctly, but it will eventually input the memorized characters, no matter which key I press (even backspace inputs characters!).

For example, if during the freeze I type "abc", the application will receive "abc" as input even if I press the backspace button three times! The "abc" pattern will keep occurring until I restart the application.

My problem is similar to this one:
[Pressing back space inputs characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395944/pressing-back-space-inputs-characters)

At first I thought it was a problem with *Skype* specifically, but it is also happening with *PyCharm* (Python IDE), which made me believe the problem is more generic (although not all applications behave like that, just these two - that I know of).

If someone have an idea of how to fix this problem I would be very grateful :-)

Comment: I have the same problem, using skype and Ubuntu 14.04. Sometimes some accented characters just stop to work, ex: áéíóú doing a'b' and etc.

Comment: I have the same issue as well, only resolution I've found is to restart it (which usually hangs at the exit screen when I try to as well, leading to having to kill it from the command line)

Comment: @Chrismit yes, exactly this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googled up a respective Launchpad bug: ["shuffled keys in keyboard buffer"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-meta/+bug/1325987).

People replace iBus with SCIM: `sudo apt-get remove ibus && sudo apt-get install scim`. I am personally cautious, as `ubuntu-desktop` depends on `ibus`.

Comment: Excellent! I've upgraded my PC recently and since then I've had no problems (probably because the number of "short freezes" was considerably reduced). I couldn't test it, but I'll accept the answer since people on launchpad confirmed it solves the issue. I hope there is no side effect :-)
Thanks!